# Using Regular Expression in VC++

Tags: regex, visual-c++

I am finding Email ids in mu project, where I am preprocessing the input using some Regular Expression.

```
RegExpPhone6.RegComp("[\[\{\(][ -]?[s][h][i][f][t][ -]?[+-][2][ -]?[\]\}\)]");
```

Here while I am compiling i am getting a warning msg like

```
Warning 39  warning C4129: ')' : unrecognized character escape sequence
```

How can i resolve this ?
Why this is occuring and Where will it affect?
Kindly help me...

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure with what kind of regex engine you are using, but according to error,

`)` is unrecognized escape, so its seems complaining about you doing `\)`.

Most of the cases, `()` and `{}` inside `[]` wouldn't need to escape just `[(){}]` would be fine.

and `[s][h][i][f][t]` would be same with `shift`

So, It will be like this

```
RegExpPhone6.RegComp("[\[{(][ -]?shift[ -]?[+-][2][ -]?[\]})]");
```

And

If it still doesn't work, try to change `\` to `\\`, sometimes need to escape backslashes.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ compiler will convert certain escape sequences in string literals into alternate values. The best known of these is probably \n, which gets converted to a linefeed character. In this case, the compiler is complaining because \) is not one of the standard set of escape sequences (A list of which can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6aw8xdf2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), among other places). Since you want the regular expression itself to contain a backslash, you probably want to use \\, which is the escape sequence that converts to a single \. Something like this:

```
RegExpPhone6.RegComp("[\\[\\{\\(][ -]?[s][h][i][f][t][ -]?[+-][2][ -]?[\\]\\}\\)]");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have escaped characters in your character class that need (and should) not be escaped, especially `()`, `[]` and `{}`.

In your case

```
RegExpPhone6.RegComp("[{([][ -]?shift[ -]?[+-][2][ -]?[]})]");
```

should do nicely.

Note that the order of the characters inside the character class matters for this to work.

`[][(){}]` will match all braces/parens/brackets. But it might throw people off ("is that an empty character class?"), so in that case, escaping the brackets might be a better idea:

```
RegExpPhone6.RegComp("[{(\[][ -]?shift[ -]?[+-][2][ -]?[\]})]");
```

See also [Jan Goyvaerts' blog](http://www.regexguru.com/2008/12/dont-escape-literal-characters-that-arent-metacharacters/) about why and where this can be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you didn't use a double quote within string?

Solve the problem using a binary search.  Get rid of half the characters and see if it compiles.
If it does compile, repeat with the other half.  Then repeat using the half of the non-compiling string until you find the character that causes the problem.  Then escape it using a backslash.

E.g. if you want to use a double-quote in a string, you have to write this:

```
"My name is \"Pat\""
```